# Как на DART распарсить сложный JSON?

Tags: json, vkontakte-api, flutter, dart

Вот JSON https://pastebin.com/rYTPjPjH полученный с vk api wall.get

Знаю что надо создать модель, наверняка создал не правильно

```
class ItemModel {
  int count;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items;

  ItemModel({
    required this.count,
    required this.items,
  });

  factory ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return ItemModel(
      count: parsedJson['count'],
      items: parsedJson['items'],
    );
  }
}
```

Дальше делаю запрос через либу http

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

и вот что дальше с response.body делать не могу понять
вообще хотел достать урлы картинок, но это наверно и сам смог если бы получить цикл всего items